# MySQL copy colmn data from one table to another row

Tags: mysql, insert

I am using phpmyadmin and trying to copy the address_id values from table address_book to the table customers row (`customers_default_billing_address_id`)

There are a few hundred addresses listed in address book and I need the address_id in the customers table. Both the customer_id in the customers table and address_book table are the same. I finally got around to not having an error but it returned 0 results and doubled the amount of customers from 314 to 628. So basically it just created new rows of empty data except for address_id.

```
INSERT into customers (`customers_default_billing_address_id`)
SELECT `address_book_id` FROM address_book
GROUP BY `customers_id`;
```

I also tried this and got grant permission problems.

```
insert into customers.customers_default_billing_address_id
SELECT `address_book_id` FROM `address_book`
inner join customers
on customers.customers_id = address_book.customers_id;
```

I then tried this and received no grant permission errors but it doubled the data in the customers table like the first attempt did.

```
insert into customers (`customers_default_billing_address_id`) SELECT `address_book_id`                  FROM `address_book` inner join customers on customers.customers_id=address_book.customers_id
```

Example

```
Table customers       
---------------                                                          
customers_id | customers_default_billing_address_id
123            0

Table address_book
------------------
customers_id | address_id
123            3256
```

**Output:**

```
Table customers        
----------------                                                                
customers_id | customers_default_billing_address_id
123            3256

Table address_book
------------------
customers_id | address_id
123            3256
```

Notice the 0 value in customers_default_billing_address_id  has been update to address_id.

Comment: @Smash: what about that?

Comment: you can copy your data in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `UPDATE` query, not `INSERT INTO`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE customers INNER JOIN
       address_book ON address_book.customer_id=customers_customer_id
     SET customers.customers_default_billing_address_id=address_book.address_book_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I need to copy all data from address_book_id from table address_book to customers_default_billing_address_id in table customers. Your code resulted in no errors but did not update each customers_default_billing_address_id with address_book_id.

Both tables have the same VALUES in customer_id. I need to move the address_book_id and associate it with the customer_id in the table customers. I started messing around with UPDATE but I am still not successful.

Comment: @user3477439: Can you please show some sample data and the desired result. That would be very helpful to make query.

Comment: I just updated with an example of what I need. Sorry for the format.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I tried using update before but no luck. Looks like I need to work on my Joins syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here and it took a minute to find the check mark.